# Threading with switch_locks doesn't modify dictionary, or throws common errors (RuntimeError, empty or Cancelled)

Tags: python, multithreading

I wrote a simple program to help me learn threading, working with dictionaries, and using switch_locks.

```
import threading
import random, string
from threading import Lock
import time

eve = True
switch_lock = Lock()


# produce random words
def wordfeed():
    global wordfeed
    wordfeed = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=5))
    x2 = threading.Thread(target=collector())
    x2.start


# collect random words
def collector():
    while eve == True:
        global a, z, wordfeed
        z = random.randint(0, 20)
# creation of buffer
        o=0
        if o==0:
            a={f'{wordfeed}': ''}
            o = o+1
        elif o>0:
# APPEND KEY-VALUE PAIRS!   
            switch_lock.acquire()
            a.add[f'{wordfeed}', f'{z}']
            switch_lock.release()
            print(a)
        x3 = threading.Thread(target=processor())
        x3.start

#iterate through and del highest values of keys
def processor():
    while eve == True:
        global a, z, wordfeed
        switch_lock.acquire()
        for key in a:
            print(a)
            if z > 18:  
                print(a)
                del a[f'{wordfeed}']
        switch_lock.release()       

wordfeed()
```

Output is either same key: value (random key, empty value), or the RuntimeError.

#s specify what I'm trying to do at each step. I can't get my mind around why I can't get this program to append and print new key:value pair, endlessly expanding the dictionary (and at the end cutting the highest values for certain pairs?

What am I not seeing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This will obviously never be false:

```
o=0
if o==0:
```

You are resetting `o` to 0 every loop, you need to initialize it outside the loop.

2. dictionaries don't have a `add()` method.

`a.add[f'{wordfeed}', f'{z}']`

It's not clear what you are trying to do, even a[f'{wordfeed}'] = f'{z}' wouldn't work since you are just overwriting the same key over and over since wordfeed never changes.

3. you never actually multithread,

```
x2 = threading.Thread(target=collector())
x2.start
```

should be

```
x2 = threading.Thread(target=collector)
x2.start()
x2.join()
```

otherwise, it means that it will pass the result of `collector()` to `Thread()` but that means it will first be evaluated by the main thread. What you want is to pass the function `collector` as a parameter so the other thread `x2` will do the task.

Here the main thread just calls `collector()`, which calls `processor()` which loops forever since `eve` is always `True`.

Also `x2.start` is a method and needs to be called. And if you don't wait for your thread to finish with `join()` the program will just end immediately and do nothing.

Honestly, that's just the tip of the iceberg. Fixing this code will teach you a lot.

Comment: “wordfeed never changes”: yes, and I don’t understand why; If my understanding is correct calling the pointer wordfeed in my code could be translated to: ‘to an empty string add a randomly generated sequence of lowercase letters, length of 5’. - I don’t get it how being called again and again, it doesn’t change its value. There’s literally a word ‘random’ there in the instruction.  If I want an infinite random strings, I’d have to declare it an infinite amount of times? Or did I make mistake somewhere? It only changes when I re-build.

Comment: thanks for all the input, it helps much more than i expected. the first one was pretty embarassing, of course, I missed it, the rest I didn’t realize. “ dictionaries don't have a add() method. “ I think I got it from some website tutorial, maybe it was wrong or obsolete and that’s why it didn’t work.

Comment: wordfeed is a string that is the result of evaluating ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=5)), this join disappears the moment it's executed and only the result remains. If you want to run it multiple times and get a new result every time what you want is to define a function that you can call repeatedly. Also you should probably rename it since wordfeed is defined twice here, as a function and as a string, this can get confusing. Kinda the same mistake as with the collector(), keep in mind that whenever you put () you aren't pointing to a function anymore but it's result.

Comment: I managed to get it to work! Almost - there's one last issue: "Exception in thread Thread-1948:
(...)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type dict). I actually NEED to make a lock that specifically waits to acquire present-state dictionary, and locks every other threads from it. So it has to be akin to switch_lock.acquire(a). Without the dict in the arg, this thing doesn't loop properly for some reason, but yes, what's after the acquire() works then. Do you know how I could accomplish that? [can't find specific solutions to lock thread until dict is acquired anywhere]. Thanks a lot again

Comment: got it to work finally! :) had to switch .pop to del and iterate through list instead dict